# What is this low-growing bush with variegated leaves and red berries?

Tags: identification, poisons, shrubs

Does anybody know what plant this is? I'd like to make sure the berries aren't poisonous for my cat.

[image]

Comment: Hi fpnick. It appears that my identification was wrong. I think Brenn has given you what you needed, which was very kind. The way the system works, I can't delete my answer while it's accepted, so would you mind changing your acceptance to Brenn's? Then I'll get mine out of the way, and you and future visitors will know exactly what this plant is. Sorry for the trouble! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to do that... Changed! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without disrespect to your answer Sue, I do believe that this is actually a variegated form of Holly (Ilex spp.). Upon closeup of some of the leaves, you will see the telltale leaf spines. Also, Euonymous berries usually, if not always, retain their "wings" and hang in clusters.

[image]

Cultivation: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/gardening/howtogrow/3295992/How-to-grow-holly.html

Image: https://www.flickr.com/photos/bob007/8109981001

Image: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/gardening/article-2009783/ASK-MONTY-Why-holly-borne-flowers-berries.html

Alas, like Euonymous, Holly berries can be toxic to humans and pets: http://www.poison.org/articles/2014-dec/holly-berries

Comment: @ Brenn- I agree with variegated holly.  I think that the first answer may have been accepted too quickly (especially without more information and close up pictures).

Comment: The image posted is quite high resolution if you click it and view at 100%. It was sufficient, in my belief, to determine it as an Ilex spp. I simply dislike chiming in and countering OP's identifications. . I'll only do so when very confident.

Comment: Hi Brenn! I appreciate your respect, but am glad you did chime in! I never even knew there were variegated hollies, and thought they all had prickly leaves. It reminded me so much of my euonymous that I spent all my time studying that plant and didn't search hard enough for similar plants with red berries! Thanks again, and also to Diane, for the correction - it's the proper information that counts, now and for future viewers. Upvote from me!

Comment: @Sue- Your answer of euonymous actually saved me from having to research what is growing in my friend's yard. So, your research (and incorrect answer) saved me a ton of time, and now I know what it is! Funny how it worked out. Thanks for that.